# Suppose that $f : C → C$ is an isometry such that $f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = 1$ and $f(i) = −i$. Prove that $f(z) = \bar z$ for all $z ∈ C$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

Suppose that $f : C → C$ is an isometry such that $f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = 1$ and $f(i) = −i$. Prove that $f(z) = \bar z$ for all $z ∈ C$.

I already have a proof for this but I would like an explanation for why this is true.

Suppose $F$ is an arbitrary isometry. Let $F_1(z) = \frac{F(z) - F(0)}{F(1) - F(0)}$. Then $|F(1)-F(0)| = 1$. So then $F_1$ is an isometry for $F_1(0) = 0$ and $F_1(1) = 1$. This is where my lack of understanding begins. It goes on to say that $F_1(i) = i$ or $F_1(i) = -i$. From this, we can say $F_1(z) = z$ or $F_1(z) = \bar z$.

So how do we know $F_1(i) = i$ or $F_1(i) = -i$? Shouldn't it be the case that only $F_1(i) = i$? I understand how it would follow from this that $F_1(z) = z$ or $F_1(z) = \bar z$ but I don't understand how it proves the original statement.

My book did not do a very good job of explaining this. Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the definition of an isometry?

Comment: Yes. A function that preserves distances. @LeeMosher

Comment: In that case, I wonder what your sentence "So then $F_1$ is an isometry for $F_1(0) = 0$ and $F_1(1) = 1$" could possibly mean. Either $F_1$ preserves distances (meaning *all* distances between *all* pairs of points) or it doesn't; either $F_1$ is an isometry or it isn't.

Comment: The book said, $F_1$ is an isometry such that $F_1(0)=0$ and $F_1(1)=1$. @LeeMosher I hope that helps.

Comment: Related: [isometry of the complex plane](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452983/isometry-of-the-complex-plane?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have $\mid F_1(i)-F_1(0)\mid =\mid i-0\mid =1$, this implies $F_1(i)=e^{ic}$. If you write $\mid F_1(i)-F_1(1)\mid^2 =\mid i-1\mid^2 =2=\mid e^{ic}-1\mid^2= (cos(c)-1)^2+sin^2(c)=2(1-cos(c))=2$. It implies $c=\pi/2$ or $c=-\pi/2$. So $F_1(i)=i$ or $F_1(i)=-i$.

Comment: How did you get that $|i-0| = 1$ and $|i-1|^2 =2$?

Comment: @Nid: Direct computation... $|x+iy|= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.