# $|f(z_1)-f(z_2)|=|z_1-z_2|$ implies $f$ being linear

Tags: complex-analysis

**Statement:**

Let $f=u+\textbf iv$, where $u, v\in C^{1}(D)$, $D$ is subdomain of complex plane. For all $z_1,z_2\in D$:
$$|f(z_1)-f(z_2)|=|z_1-z_2|$$
Prove, that $f(z)=\exp\{\textbf i\theta\} z + a$ or $f(z)=\exp\{\textbf i\theta\} \bar z + a$, where $\theta\in\mathbb R$ and $a\in\mathbb C$.

**My ideas:**

Suppose that $f$ is holomorphic in $D$. Then due to the statement equation we have that $|f'|\equiv 1$ in $D$. It implies that all functions like $$f(z)=\exp\{\textbf i\theta\} z + a$$ are solutions.
Another idea I came up with with is that if $f(z)$ is a solution, then $\bar f(z), f(\bar z), \bar f(\bar z)$ are solutions too. So we get that all functions like $$f(z)=\exp\{\textbf i\theta\} \bar z + a$$
are solutions.
The reasoning is true when $f$ is supposed to be holomorphic. The problem is in the "$\mathbb C$-differentiation" paragraph, so applying $\frac{\partial }{\partial z}$ or $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}$ can help, but I haven't come up with anything.

Comment: Already answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452983/isometry-of-the-complex-plane) (although phrased a bit different)

Comment: @JulioPuerta Thank you! I looked this post through. Firstly, it is about the whole complex plane isometry, here we have the subdomain of complex plane. Secondly, their solutions use constructive approach with some 2d-geometry ideas, but my problem's placed in complex-differentiation paragraph.

Comment: I feel it's a bit difficult to prove this result without using at least one geometric argument. I will try to write an answer.

Comment: @JulioPuerta If you succeed, I will be very grateful

Comment: It's a weird Q, as you don't need the $C^1$ assumption on $u$ and $v$. It's possible to come up with a more analytical argument with this assumption, though. EG sketch: $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ itself is $C^1$. The total derivative must itself be an isometry, and hence it's in $O(2)$. By continuity, the determinant is constant, and after possibly taking the conjugate, assume it's constantly $1$. It follows that $f$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations, so is holomorphic. Hence $f'$ is holomorphic. But $|f'(z)| = 1$, so $f'$ must be constant for various reasons. (EG open mapping theorem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WLOG, we may assume $0\in D$ (otherwise we can perform a translation and then apply $f$). As $D$ is a domain, we may find $r\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $B(0,r)\subseteq D$.

We prove a lemma first:

**Lemma**: Let $h$ be an isometry defined in a domain $D$ such that $h(0)=0$, $h(r/2)=r/2$ and $h(ir/2)=ir/2$, where $r\in\mathbb{R}$ is such that $r/2, ir/2\in D$. Then $h$ is the identity.

As $h$ is an isometry, $|h(z)-h(w)|=|z-w|$ for $z,w\in D$. Taking $w=0, r/2$ and $ir/2$ respectively, we get that $$|h(z)|=|z|, \space|h(z)-r/2|=|z-r/2|, \space|h(z)-ri/2|=|z-ri/2|$$ So $h(z)$ and $z$ are the same distance from $0,r/2$ and $ri/2$. As three circles intersect in at most one point (this can also be proved analitically, try it!), necessarily $h(z)=z, \forall z\in D$. $\space\blacksquare$

Let's now consider the function $k(z)=\dfrac{r}{2}\dfrac{f(z)-f(0)}{f(r/2)-f(0)}$. It is obvious $k$ is an isometry and that it fixes $0$ and $r/2$. Then, $$|k(ir/2)|=|k(ir/2)-k(0)|=|ir/2-0|=r/2$$ and $$\space |k(ir/2)-r/2|=|k(ir/2)-k(r/2)|=|ir/2-r/2|=r/\sqrt{2}$$

So $k(ir/2)$ is in the circle around $0$ with radius $r/2$ and the circle around $r/2$ with radius $r/\sqrt{2}$. The only two points in both circles are $ir/2$ and $-ir/2$. If $k(ir/2)=ir/2$, then, by the lemma, $k$ is the identity. If $k(ir/2)=-ir/2$ then $\overline{k}$ verifies the lemma, so $\overline{k}$ is the identity, and $k(z)=\overline{z}$.

In any case, naming $\alpha=\dfrac{2(f(r/2)-f(0))}{r}$ and $\beta=f(0)$, we see that $|\alpha|=1$ and $f(z)=\alpha k(z)+\beta$, so $f$ has the desired form.

This proof doesn't rely on $f$ being differentiable. In fact, if $f$ is differentiable the result can be quickly obtained as you mentioned.

Comment: Can your lemma be generalized to the form: "If 2d-isometry has 3 fixed points then it is the identity"?

Comment: The points need to be not collinear. For example, reflecting respect to a line fixes that entire line.

Comment: Of course. So we have "2d-isometry with 3 fixed points not lying on the same straight line is the identity" then?

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Comment: Then your proof is clear to me. Thank you! But I am still puzzled with this problem being in the paragraph it is :( Anyway, thanks again!